# How can I solve this nonlinear-projection optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, projection, mixed-integer-programming

How can I solve this nonlinear projection problem?
Can you give me any idea?

Constraints are as shown in the image.
The norm can be anyone.

Variables : $z_1,\;z_2,\;\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d,\;\overline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d,\;\underline{y},\;\overline{y}$
$\hat{x}\in \mathbb{R}^d, \; \hat{y}$ are data, and $y,\;\hat{y}$ are 1 or -1.

$z_1 \geq 0,\; z_2 \geq 0, \;z_1+z_2 \geq 0$
$z_1 (\lVert \underline{x} - \hat{x} \rVert +  \lvert {\underline{y}-\hat{y}} \rvert )
+z_2 (\lVert \overline{x} - \hat{x} \rVert + \lvert {\overline{y}-\hat{y}} \rvert) \leq \epsilon $

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Assuming $\epsilon \ge 0$, $z_1=0=z_2$ satisfies all constraints, regardless of values of the other variables. The question title mentions "optimization" but I'm not seeing any objective function.

Comment: @prubin Sorry for that. This is a 'least square problem'. I want to project the result of gradient descent (whose shape is same as [z1, z2, x_, x^,y_,y^]) into this constraints.

Comment: Project in such a way that $\underline{y}$ and $\overline{y}$ (I assume these are the results of projecting) are in $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$ (as opposed to in $[0,1]$)?

Comment: @prubin Yes. That's it.

Comment: What is the specific objective function? I'm try to see why setting $\underline{y}=\overline{y}=\hat{y}$ and $\underline{x}=\overline{x}=\hat{x}$ (which is feasible for any choice of $z_1$ and $z_2$ does not automatically produce (or extend to) an optimal solution.

Comment: @prubin I reposted my problem newly. Could you take a look at my new post? Thank you very much.